# How to apply if/else logic in where clause?

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, where-clause

I have logic that is based on `If/Else` statement. This should be applied in SQL where clause filter. Here is example on how that should look like:

```
if (type = 'DEV') { // If type is DEV then status should be Y
   status = 'Y'
}else{ // If not do not apply filter
   1=1
}
```

I have tried this in SQL:

```
WHERE id IN (89,56,87)
   AND ( 
           (type = 'TRNG' AND status = 'Y') 
           OR 
           (1=1)
        )
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve what I have in if/else statement?

Comment: @jarlh I'm still getting DEV in my result set...

Comment: Sorry... Don't hang up, back in a minute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you seem to be looking for :

```
WHERE id IN (89,56,87) AND ( type <> 'DEV' OR status = 'Y')
```

This means : if `type` is `'DEV'`, then `status` must be equal to `'Y'`. This implies that if `type` is different than `DEV`, then any value of `status` is allowed.